# Alter a SQL server function to accept new optional parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I already have a function in SQL Server 2005 as:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fCalculateEstimateDate] (@vWorkOrderID numeric)
Returns varchar(100)  AS
Begin
  <Function Body>
End
```

I want to modify this function to accept addition optional parameter @ToDate. I am going to add logic in function if @Todate Provided then do something else continue with existing code.

I modified the function as:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fCalculateEstimateDate] (@vWorkOrderID numeric,@ToDate DateTime=null)
Returns varchar(100)  AS
Begin
  <Function Body>
End
```

Now I can call function as:

```
SELECT dbo.fCalculateEstimateDate(647,GETDATE())
```

But it gives error on following call:

```
SELECT dbo.fCalculateEstimateDate(647)
```

as

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or
> function dbo.fCalculateEstimateDate.

which as per my understanding should not happen.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

From [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

> When a parameter of the function has a default value, the keyword `DEFAULT` must be specified when the function is called to retrieve the default value. This behavior is different from using parameters with default values in stored procedures in which omitting the parameter also implies the default value.

So you need to do:

```
SELECT dbo.fCalculateEstimateDate(647,DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep SELECT dbo.fCalculateEstimateDate(647) call working??

Comment: No. Each call to the function must have the same number of parameters specified. You could always create a *new* function with two parameters, and turn `dbo.fCalculateEstimateDate` into a wrapper function that simply adds the second parameter to call the new function.

Comment: why on earth does this differ from Stored procedures? Im pretty sure you can just skip the second parameter and it would just work!

Comment: @Peter - T-SQL is a *very* crufty language. With lots of warts in odd and surprising places. I can't give you an actual reason for the different, but since stored procedures always appear in standalone contexts rather than as part of larger statements, it's may be parse related.

Comment: @Peter it was written by people with no common sense or db using experience

Comment: @Peter What I think because we can't call function in SQL by setting its parameters values like Stored Procedure. Hence it can't be decided that, which parameters to ignore by function.

Comment: @Peter "I am pretty sure" is different to "I read the documentation and I tried it".  Accept it. Default parameters are handled differently in procedures and functions.

Answer (score 32):

The way to keep `SELECT dbo.fCalculateEstimateDate(647)` call working is:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fCalculateEstimateDate] (@vWorkOrderID numeric)
Returns varchar(100)  AS
   Declare @Result varchar(100)
   SELECT @Result = [dbo].[fCalculateEstimateDate_v2] (@vWorkOrderID,DEFAULT)
   Return @Result
Begin
End

CREATE function [dbo].[fCalculateEstimateDate_v2] (@vWorkOrderID numeric,@ToDate DateTime=null)
Returns varchar(100)  AS
Begin
  <Function Body>
End
```

Comment: Can't you just say `RETURN [dbo].[fCalculateEstimateDate_v2] (@vWorkOrderID,DEFAULT)` ?

Comment: Yes! sure. It´s the same

Answer (score 2):

I have found the EXECUTE command as suggested here [T-SQL - function with default parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358315/t-sql-function-with-default-parameters) to work well.  With this approach there is no 'DEFAULT' needed when calling the function, you just omit the parameter as you would with a stored procedure.

Comment: If you're calling a UDF from within another query (e.g. a scalar function in a `SELECT`, or a table-valued function in a `FROM` or `JOIN`) then you can't use `EXECUTE` btw. But what's wrong with using the `DEFAULT` keyword? I really can't think of any good reason to not use it, and your function has too many optional parameters then you should refactor it into differently-named functions, imo.