# Are these 'Table Hints' SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Not quite sure what these are to be honest. I am looking at someone else's `SQL query` and they have `SELECT` statements which look like this:

```
SELECT 
    Something,
    Something
FROM
MyTable(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
```

And Another which looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    Something,
    Something
FROM
MyTable(NULL)
```

Christ, when I do a `SELECT` statement, I only put the table name there and that's it.

Could someone please tell me what the `(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)` would be used for? and also the `(NULL)` - I'm sure there are many more of these once I know what they are.

My apologies if this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Are you sure that is a table, it could be a function(?)

Comment: MyTable isn't a table, it's a table function requiring 3 parameters in the former statement and 1 in the second.

Comment: Also thought it was a function, but cant seem to find the function they are calling. So I assumed table as there was a table with the same name.

Comment: you are both probably 100% correct, I'm going to dig for this function I cant seem to find :) Thank you though! Thought I was losing my mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL - function with default parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358315/t-sql-function-with-default-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that MyTable(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) is a table-valued function call. This function has three parameters, and all these parameters should take default values.

Comment: Was indeed a function, Wasn't on the DB I was looking at because they are using `Synonyms` Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

In Management Studio, Look under Programmability->Functions->Table-valued Functions. There you will see the definition of the function.

Comment: What question does this answer?

Comment: The definition of the function will explain the function definition and show what the arguments are for.

Comment: Why the downvote? The information is meant to help the asker to find the source code and explain the call!

Comment: I am just trying to help.. It shows where to find the definition of the function used, and thus explains what the DEFAULT-values are and what they are used for, which is exactly what is asked.. imho..

Comment: _"It shows where to find the definition of the function used"_ - yeah, and _just that_. OP didn't even know it was a function call. The question is not _"How can I see a list of table-valued functions in my database"_.

Comment: What is wrong with informing, by showing where to find the actual function call so he can see for himself what the parameters are used for, instead of just giving a general statement like 'it is a function call' (which I also did in a comment..)

Comment: Compare your answer to the accepted answer. Answers should be self-contained. Your answer does not explain anything.

Comment: Well, sorry, but I disagree. Moving on.