# Errors while Trying to Use a Function Parameter inside an IF Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

I have the following `CREATE FUNCTION`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufnTotalSales (@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime = GETDATE(), @FoodName nvarchar(50) = '')
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    (
        IF @FoodName = '';
        BEGIN
            SELECT f.FoodID, FoodName, (FoodPrice * Quantity) AS TotalSales FROM Food f, OrderFoodRel ofr
            WHERE (Date_Time BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT f.FoodID, FoodName, (FoodPrice * Quantity) AS TotalSales FROM Food f, OrderFoodRel ofr
            WHERE (Date_Time BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) AND @FoodName = FoodName
        END
    );
```

The first error occurs at `@EndDate datetime = GETDATE()`, it says `Incorrect syntax near '()'`. I'm trying to assign the `@EndDate` parameter a default value of the current `datetime` if the user opts to use the default value, but somehow I get an error.

The second error occurs at all the parameters that I used in `IF ... ELSE` block (`@FoodName`, `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`). It says that I `Must declare the scalar variable "@..."`. It's a parameter and not a scalar variable, how do I fix this?

The idea of this function is to return the total sales of food(s) with two options: one being the total sales of a food with name X from a date to another date if you specified the food name; and two being the total sales of food(s) from a date to another date disregarding the food name.

Comment: How OrderFoodRel and Food is related

Comment: @SanalSunny They are related using the primary key from Food (FoodID). OrderFoodRel has a foreign key FoodID that points to said primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several issue with the function

Firstly, you can't have default value assign to functionyou can't use `IF .. ELSE` inside a function
Secondly. the tables `Food` and `OrderFoodRel` are not `JOINed`. You are doing a cross join here

It doesn't like getdate() as default value, you can set NULL as default for the `@EndDate` and use `ISNULL()` on the `@EndDate`

this is will create the function. I assumed the 2 tables are related by `FoodID`

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufnTotalSales 
(
    @StartDate datetime,  
    @EndDate   datetime     = NULL, 
    @FoodName  nvarchar(50) = ''
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT  f.FoodID, FoodName, (FoodPrice * Quantity) AS TotalSales 
        FROM    Food f
                INNER JOIN OrderFoodRel ofr on  f.FoodID    = ofr.FoodID
        WHERE   Date_Time BETWEEN @StartDate AND ISNULL(@EndDate, GETDATE())
        AND     (
                    @FoodName   = ''
                OR  f.FoodName  = @FoodName
                )
    );
GO
```

So to use the default value on the input, you need to use the keyword `default`

```
select  *
from    dbo.ufnTotalSales('2018-10-01', default , default)
```

Comment: However, there is a post in regard to assigning a parameter a default value here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358315/t-sql-function-with-default-parameters

Comment: edited the query. OK. it does not like `getdate()` as default value. Only constant

Comment: For the last part FoodName = '' OR f.FoodName = FoodName, is it correct if I say that that last part means: if FoodName is an empty string (the default value), then any FoodName fulfills that condition; buat if it isn't, check the second condition which is comparing the FoodName from my Food table with the parameter inserted (which is no longer an empty string)?

Comment: Also, how do I set so that if the user opts to not use specify the EndDate, it will default to the datetime of now? Is it using COALESCE as the other answers have provided? I think that it's correct since COALESCE will always choose the GETDATE() option when EndDate is not specified, I guess I'm asking for reassurance.

Comment: edited the answer to include that. Yes `ISNULL()` and `COALESCE()` works the same in this case

Comment: Okay, thank you! As for the first part of my question, regarding the last part of FoodName = '' OR f.FoodName = FoodName. Is my logic correct?

Comment: yes. your logic / understanding on that  is correct

Comment: Thank you :-)! I understand what I got wrong now. How did you know that I'm not allowed to use IF ... ELSE inside a function? Is there an official explanation in regard to that matter?

Comment: `mposes conditions on the execution of a Transact-SQL statement` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017  . Your function defined as `RETURNS TABLE`. So the `RETURN` portion should be a query that returns a single result. Hence not allow any flow control logic. If you do required any conditional checking use `CASE WHEN`

Comment: Or to be more specific, you can't use `IF..ELSE` in table value function, it is fine in scalar function

Answer (score 1):

You can't use procedural logic inside an ITVF, rather you can only use a query of some sort which returns a result set.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

The following is hopefully close to what you are looking for:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufnTotalSales
(
  @StartDate datetime
  , @EndDate datetime
  , @FoodName nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  SELECT f.FoodID, FoodName, (FoodPrice * Quantity) AS TotalSales FROM Food f, OrderFoodRel ofr
  WHERE (Date_Time BETWEEN @StartDate AND coalesce(@EndDate,getdate()))
  and coalesce(@FoodName,'') = ''
  union all
  SELECT f.FoodID, FoodName, (FoodPrice * Quantity) AS TotalSales FROM Food f, OrderFoodRel ofr
  WHERE (Date_Time BETWEEN @StartDate AND coalesce(@EndDate,getdate()))
  AND coalesce(@FoodName,'') = FoodName
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358315/t-sql-function-with-default-parameters There is a post about default parameters, though. Or does that only work with scalar-valued functions?

Comment: You're correct sorry - you can have defaults, but the default has to be a static value, not a function call like getdate(). But I would do it the way I have and pass null in or set the default to null if you don't want to have to pass the parameter in.

Comment: If I want the @EndDate to be the datetime of now and I call the function without that parameter, won't it return the same error as problem in said link ('An insufficient number of parameters were supplied')?

Comment: Sorry you're (sort of) right again, best to read the reference link as it tells you exactly how to do it. You could set defaults (of say null) and then when you call the function you have to pass the keyword `default` in instead of a value. Personally I would just pass null in and not use defaults - but up to you.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer! How did you know that I can't use procedural logic inside an ITVF? Did it come with experience or is there an explicit explanation of that rule?

Comment: If you check the reference docs (the link I posted) under ITVF it says `RETURN [ ( ] select_stmt [ ) ] ` and then further down it defines what `select_stmt` is.

Comment: I see, thank you again! Unfortunately, I've chosen to accept another answer. Nevertheless, yours helped me a lot in understanding what I got wrong, too. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below function

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufnTotalSales 
(  @StartDate datetime, 
   @EndDate datetime, 
   @FoodName nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT f.FoodID, FoodName, (FoodPrice * Quantity) AS TotalSales 
        FROM Food f
        JOIN OrderFoodRel ofr on f.FoodID = ofr.FoodID
        WHERE (Date_Time BETWEEN @StartDate AND ISNULL(@EndDate,GETDATE())) 
         AND ISNULL(@FoodName,'') = FoodName

    );
```

Comment: That doesn't help with the fact that there is procedural logic within an ITVF though.

Comment: @WealthyPlayer please try now